# Is there is any compile time function in Android ?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, compilation

I want to do a programmatic check of my libraries (configuration check)  in my android app during compilation. Is there is method which I can use to run this code segment only during compilation. I tried, but when i try to access the project folder using  System.getProperty("user.dir") , it shows the path inside the device. hence i am not able to access the libs folder. Can anyone help me in this and give me some idea as to how to proceed  with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/). You can write an annotation processor to run code at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String getBuildTime(String pacakgename,Context context){

           String buildtime=null;
            try{
                 ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(pacakgename, 0);
                 ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ai.sourceDir);
                 ZipEntry ze = zf.getEntry("classes.dex");
                 long time = ze.getTime();
                 buildtime = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(new java.util.Date(time));

              }catch(Exception e){
              }

            return buildtime;

     }
```